# How to use jQuery datetimepicker plugin with Django

Tags: jquery, django

I'm a beginner with Django, working on my first project. For the main functionality of the site I need to use a `datetimepicker`. Since it's impossible to use Bootstrap (incompatible with Django 1.11) it looks that the only(?) option which I could handle is this one: [jquery `datetimepicker` plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/).

I tried to configure it, but unfortunately I see no result at my site. My code:

#### Forms.py

```py
time_from = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'datetimepicker'}))
```

#### Template - base.html

I put jQuery and jQueryUI into static directory, add  path to them into head section and `{% load static %}` between html tag and head. At the and of the file I have links to the datetimepicker.

```html
<html>
{% load static %}
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>placyk</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
            <p>Nothing</p>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/datetimepicker-master/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
    <script src="/static/datetimepicker-master/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/datetimepicker-master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

#### Template - specific for the view, extends base.html

```html
<html>
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
    {% block title %}<title>Dodaj wizytę</title>{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}        
    <form action="{% url 'add_visit' user.id %}" method='post'>
        {{form}}
        <input type='submit' value="Submit">
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
    {% if msg %}
        <a href='/home_login'>Strona główna</a>
        {{msg}}
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

#### Views.py

```py
class AddVisitView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, id):
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        form = AddVisitForm(user=user)
        ctx = {'form': form, 'user': user}
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'add_visit.html', ctx)

    def post(self, request, id):
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        form = AddVisitForm(user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pground_id = form.cleaned_data['pground']
            time_from = form.cleaned_data['time_from']
            time_to = form.cleaned_data['time_to']
            visit = Visit.objects.create(pground_id = pground_id, time_from=time_from, time_to=time_to, who=user)
            ctx = {'msg': 'Visit added!', 'user': user}
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'add_visit.html', ctx)
        else:
            ctx = {'form': form, 'user': user}
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'add_visit.html', ctx)
```

Would you be so kind and comment what did I wrong and how I could get a `datetimepicker` on my site?

Comment: Firstly, try changing the way you point to static files. Use {% static "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" %}, see if that helps.

Comment: Server shows an error in the template - no such tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an id selector instead of class selector when attaching the datetimepicker

i.e.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
```

Examples: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: Ok, I changed the selector in a template: $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker() and in a form: {'id': 'datetimepicker'}. Still nothing...

Comment: I didn't manage to install working jQuery plugin so I eventually downgrade my Django to 1.10 (using requirements.txt option) and used Bootstrap datetimepicker.